# Find a point perpendicular to the middle of a line LineRenderer

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, math

[exemple](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GldH2.png)

I use line renderer to draw a line and then use the start and end as the only points.
This makes a perfect line of two points, then I added in the middle of the line so 3 points.

I want to make and animation and i have to move the middle point on the perpendicular to the line.

To resume it that it is easier to understand, in the end, if i move move point on this perpendicular "axis", it will create an isosceles triangle.

```cs
//mid
float x = start.x + (end.x  - start.x) / 2;
float y = start.y + (end.y - start.y) / 2;

Vector2 mid = new Vector2(x, y);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to the usage of `Vector2` I will assume you mean in 2D space, otherwise in 3D there would be an infinite amount of points placed on a circle around the center of your line ;)

You can use [`Vector2.Perpendicular`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector2.Perpendicular.html).

However, what you need to pass in would not be a position but rather a direction and should look like e.g.

```
// center point of your line
var mid = (start + end) / 2f;
// direction of your line
var direction = (end - start).normalized;
// perpendicular direction
var perpendicularDirection = Vector2.Perpendicular(direction).noramlized;
// and finally the point C is starting from the center point go in perpendicular direction
var c = mid + perpendicularDirection * DISTANCE;
```

where you still need to fill in the `DISTANCE`

---

Little demo

```
public class Example : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform A;
    public Transform B;
    public Transform C;
    public LineRenderer Line;
    public float distance;

    private void Update()
    {
        var start = (Vector2)A.position;
        var end = (Vector2)B.position;

        Line.SetPosition(0, start);
        Line.SetPosition(1, end);

        // center point of your line
        var mid = (start + end) / 2f;

        // direction of your line
        var direction = (end - start).normalized;

        // perpendicular direction
        var perpendicularDirection = Vector2.Perpendicular(direction).normalized;

        // and finally the point C is starting from the center point go in perpendicular direction
        var c = mid + perpendicularDirection * distance;

        C.position = c;
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Your answer is amazing, i have everything that i needed. Now i can draw a line and make a bouncy animation that looks incredible, thank you so much.

Answer (score -1):

To find the midpoint of two points (your 'start' and 'end' points), you can just add the points together and then divide by 2:

```
var mid = ( start + end ) / 2;
var direction = end - start;
var perp = Vector2.Perpendicular(direction);
```

You'll now have a vector that is perpendicular to your line segment. Now you'll just have to determine how far along that perpendicular you'd like to travel, and reposition it to start at the `mid` point:

```
var apex = (perp.normalized * height) + mid;
```

Where `apex` here is 'C' in your example diagram, and `height` is a value you define.

Comment: This is not exactly how to use `Perpendicular` ... you are passing in a position .. you would rather want to pass in a **direction** ... also adding `mid` to the(supposedly) perpendicular direction before normalizing it makes no sense. You rather want first a normalized direction perpendicular to `A -> B` and then start from the `mid` and go in this direction the desired amount. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74149353/7111561)

Comment: @derHugo you're right. `mid` should be added in to the 'apex' calculation, as the origin, not the perp calculation. Updating the code.

Comment: well tbh yes .. now after applying what I said and basically copying my code it would work ;) .. the `( .. )` in the last line are redundant btw ;)